# Access component variable inside subscribe() within ionViewDidLoad()

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, rxjs

I have the following code in my component and the chats.push() function in the method ionViewDidLoad generates an error:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-messages',
  templateUrl: 'messages.html'
})
export class MessagesPage {

  currentUser: User;
  chats: Chat[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private _auth: AuthService, private _db: DatabaseService, private _user: UserService) {

    console.log('constructor MessagesPage');

    // Get currently authenticated user
    this.currentUser = this._auth.currentUser;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    //console.log(this.chats.length);

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MessagesPage');

    // Load chats
    this._user.getChatsAsObservableList(this.currentUser.uid).subscribe(tmpChats => {

      tmpChats.forEach(tmpChat => {

        console.log(tmpChat);
        // Retrieve chat id
        let chatId = tmpChat.$key;
        console.log('Retrieving a chat with id ', chatId);

        // Instantiate a Chat object
        let chat = new Chat(chatId, tmpChat);

        // Retrieve its members
        let chatMembers = this._db.getChatMembersAsObservableList(chatId);
        // For each member retrieve the user info and add it the members of the Chat object
        chatMembers.subscribe(members => {
          members.forEach(member => {
            this.addMemberToChat(chatId, member.$key);
          });
        });

        // finally add the chat to the chat list
        this.chats.push(chat); // Generates an ERROR : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
        console.log('Chat:', chat);
      });
    });
  }

  // Methods
  addMemberToChat(chat: Chat, uid: string) {
    if (uid) {
      let userAsObservableObj = this._user.getUserAsObservableObj(uid);
      let user = new User(uid, userAsObservableObj);
      chat.members.push(user);
    } else {
      console.log('Could not add member to Chat object because uid was empty.');
    }
  }

}
```

I imagine it is a "this" problem and I see many post about this but I could not manage to solve it with the fat arrow. I guess that is because I have several level of promises...

How could I solve this ?

Comment: I don't see an `this` problem. I wonder why you pass a `chatId` to `addMemberToChat(...)` and then receive it as `chat:Chat` and access it's `members` to `push(user)`. I'd assume `chatId` to be a number or string, not a complex object.

Comment: Try initializing the chat variable, like `chats: Chat[] = [];`

Comment: You are right, that was a mistake, code should have been this.addMemberToChat(chat, member.$key). Do you have any idea why I have this undefined issue remaining though?

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, that solved the issue!

Comment: I get pretty confused though about how arrow functions capture different levels of promises... any good documentation on this?

Answer (score 1):

Initializing chats solved the issue:

```
chats: Chat[] = [];
```